# Python: Conditionally Compare CSV row value

Tags: python, csv

I have the following CSV file.

```
Item Number,Item Description,List Price,QTY Available
3079-000-006-000,Covert GTX Liner Size 6,99.99,8
3079-000-007-000,Covert GTX Liner Size 7,99.99,36
3079-000-008-000,Covert GTX Liner Size 8,99.99,181
```

I need to limit the QTY Available to 10. So If row[3] is greater than 10 I want the value 10 to show up in that role. So far I have:

```
import csv
import os

inputFileName = "temp.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"

with open(inputFileName, "rb") as inFile, open(outputFileName, "wb") as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(inFile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    r.next()  
    w.writerow(['Item Number', 'Item Description', 'List Price', 'QTY Available'])

    for row in r:
        if row[3] >= 10:
            row[3] = 10
        w.writerow(row)
```

This turns all the values in the QTY Available column to 10 however I only want to change the ones that exceed 10. How can I limit the values to 10?

Comment: Sorry that was a copy error I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings and integers; turn `row(10)` into an integer first before comparing:

```
for row in r:
    if int(row[3]) >= 10:
        row[3] = 10
    w.writerow(row)
```

It doesn't matter that you set `row[3]` to an integer for *output* as the `csv.writer()` will turn it back to a string again for you.